# Redux state changes but shouldn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem. I have a simple Grid and the Grid gets its data from the redux state. But when I sort, I noticed that my data changes in the state, which it shouldn't or I missunderstood redux at this point. 
Here a bit of code

reducer:

```
const gridOptions = {
 columns: ["id", "name", "lastname"],
 data: [
  {id: 1, name: "test", lastname: "test2"},
  {id: 2, name: "test1", lastname: "test3"}
 ],
 sortBy: {},
 filter: {}
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 data: function (state = gridOptions.data, action) {
  return [...state];
 },
 selectedRow: function (state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case "ROW_SELECTED":
     return action.data
   default:
    return state
 }
},
sortBy: function (state = gridOptions.sortBy, action) {
switch (action.type) {
  case "SORT_CHANGE":
    return Object.assign({}, action.column);
  default:
    return state;
 }
},
columns: function (state = gridOptions.columns, action) {
 return state;
},
filter: function (state = gridOptions.filter, action) {
  return state;
 }
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

the container component. I know it is a bit messy.

```
var mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
  data: (() => {
   if (!state.sortBy) {
    return state.data
   } else {
    return state.data.sort()
   }
  })(),
  selectedRow: state.selectedRow,
  sortBy: state.sortBy
 } 
}

var mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
  onRowSelected: data => dispatch({type: "ROW_SELECTED", data}),
  onSortChange: column => {
    dispatch({type: "SORT_CHANGE", column})
  },
  onFilter: filterText => {
    dispatch({type: "FILTER_CHANGE", filterText})
  }
 }
}
```

So now to the question. For some reason I don't understand ... if I console.log the `state.data` ...everytime it gets sorted, the `state.data` gets mutated...which is not suppose to happen. But the real question is. why? Or do I missunderstand redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at what `.sort()` actually does it [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array

So your `mapStateToProps` is actually mutating the state. There's nothing in redux that stops you from doing this, you have to take care of keeping the state immutable yourself.

This should be solved by using (for example)

```
return [...state.data].sort()
```

Or some other way to clone the array before sorting it.

You can replicate this in the browser console by running these two lines and comparing the output

```
var a = [2,1]; console.log(a.sort()); console.log(a)
var a = [2,1]; console.log([...a].sort()); console.log(a)
```

The first one will change the original array, the second will not.

Comment: Oh thank you very much...it worked. I tested it if the sort function was the problem but I came out negative. maybe I overlooked something. But thank you. it worked

Comment: Glad it worked. Added the minimal code that will demonstrate this behaviour, you can run it from the F12 console and observe the output.